# Set a static front-page as a landing page programmatically

Tags: theme-development, frontpage

I am in process to create my first wordpress theme with underscores.me skeleton, 
the theme i would like to create its a business theme so when my theme is activated to land directly to a static front-page instead of the default wp posts. How could i do this programmatically and where to put this code (for example at functions.php file) and where to call it. I know i could change this from wp dashboard but instead i would like to do it programmatically and if a user wants to display wp post as the home page to be able to do it from wp dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by targeting `get_option('show_on_front');`

some code which could help would be:

```
function themename_after_setup_theme() {
 $site_type = get_option('show_on_front');
 if($site_type == 'posts') {
  update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
  update_option( 'page_for_posts', 'page-name' );
 }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'themename_after_setup_theme' );
```

This will run on theme activation only, remember to change the page-name to the page you want to be set as the homepage.

This isn't tested but have used this on a similar project before